# Server access outside local network (Without Manually opening ports)

Tags: ssh, routing

I am relativity new to Linux systems and am faced with the following problem:

I have n servers behind a n local router (different networks), i would like to access this servers via port 80 from outside the local networks.

The general setup is the following:

```
               _____________________________
Client 1 <===> |                            | <===> [ROUTER 1] <===> Local Server 1
Client 2 <===> |         Net Server          |
               |   (External IP /Internet)  | <===> [ROUTER 2] <===> Local Server 2
Client 3 <===> |                            | <===> [ROUTER 3] <===> Local Server 3
Client n <===> |____________________________| <===> [ROUTER n] <===> Local Server n
```

The challenge is to do this **WITHOUT MANUALLY** forwarding port 80 on routers. ( ie logging into local router 'n' and changing settings)

Is this possible ? (SSH Tunnel .... ?)

Your input would be much appreciated

Comment: Maybe the system administrator can help you out with this.

Answer (score 0):

SSH tunneling would work if you have a way to ssh somehow inside of the network.  Those who want to access the site on port 80 would have to setup their SSH client and SSH forwarding beforehand.

If you can run an OpenVPN server outside of your network, you can configure OpenVPN as a client on the servers.  The servers will then make an outgoing connection to the external OpenVPN server.  You can then connect to that OpenVPN server as another client and access the servers over port 80 on the virtual network.

Other than that, no way.